# Can the volume Integral of a non zero function be zero?

Tags: integration

Can the volume Integral of a non zero function be zero? e.g if i evaluate the triple integral of:
$$ xy^2 +2yz^2 $$ bounded by $$-1<x,y,z < 1$$ 
I get zero when I evauluate this.

Comment: Why do you think it can't?

Comment: Indeed, the terms $xy^2$ and $2yz^2$ both have integral zero on your cube.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.It can be zero.Suppose you are evaluating double integral over some area and the part of graph above and below $xy$ plane is same,then u will get zero there. Similar case occurs in volume integral.